# How to horizontal center the title in Material-UI AppBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I can not find a way to center the title in React Material UI AppBar. Maybe I am missing something. Few other answers are there on StackOverflow but those don't seem to be the best way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use material-ui makeStyles to center the text:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
}));
```

And than apply 'title' style to your title component:

```
export default function CenteredTextAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            Centered Text
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can refer to this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-w924i?fontsize=14) example.

Comment: what about if there is a back button on the top left margin (ie to the left of the title). Can one keep the title centered?